# Does firestore rule simulator account for existing documents actual collections?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Does firebase/firestore rule simulator account for existing actual collections? For example, I have a collection named "users" and the rule

```
match /users/{uniq_username} {
        // let authed users create new uniq names
        allow create: if request.auth != null 
                      && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(uniq_username))
```

to check that a document does not already exist in that collection under the same name. I currently have a single document in the actual collection named "XXX". When doing a *create* operation in the firestore rules simulator, for data of the form

```
{"__name__":"/databases/(default)/documents/users/XXX","data":{some data...}}
```

expecting do get "permission denied" (since the document "XXX" already exists in the actual collection), instead getting "access allowed".

So is there something wrong with the `exists` rule as I am using it here or does the firestore rules simulator just not account for the actual documents in the collection when running simulations?

Comment: The simulator should use the actual contents of your database when testing rules.

Comment: As Doug said, the simulator should definitely check against the actual data. It is hard to see why that doesn't seem to be happening here with the information you currently provided. Can you provide a screenshot of the simulator showing the write operation you're trying? While you're at it, please also add a screenshot showing that the document already exists in the collection.

Comment: @DougStevenson I see. Something was in fact wrong with *the way I had written my rules* (no ending semicolon). But since could not find any docs explicating that the simulator used the actual database, I'm thinking this may be an OK question to leave on SO for others debugging like myself. If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.